# Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p_categories.id'

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, api, postman

For my laravel project, I created the product category table and add data to the table. Now I need to get each product_category detail using get method.

This is the product category table that I created,

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('p_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('category_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

CategoryController I use,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\PCategory;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
//
function addPCategory(Request $req)
{
    $pcategory=new PCategory;
    $pcategory->name=$req->input('name');
    $pcategory->size=$req->input('size');
    $pcategory->save();
    return $pcategory;
}

 function getCategory($id)
 {
    return PCategory :: find($id);
 }
}
```

In api.php I use,

```
  Route :: post('addPCategory',[CategoryController::class,'addPCategory']);
  Route :: get('Category/{id}',[CategoryController::class,'getCategory']);
```

I am getting this error in postman

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p_categories.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `p_categories` where `p_categories`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What dose this have to do with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an `id` column on your `p_catgeories` table, you can either add one by doing `$table->id()` or you will have to use `category_id` instead of `id`.

The problem is that the `::find()` method is defaultly looking for the `id` column. If you really want `category_id` instead of `id`, you could overwrite or rewrite this function.

You could also add: `protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';` to your `PCategroy` Model and `find()` will work fine again.

Comment: Now its working really fine. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am glad it works, if you could accept my answer that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

find($id) method assumes your tables's index is named 'id' but yours is category_id.
Replace

```php
    return PCategory :: find($id);
```

with

```php
    return PCategory :: where('category_id',$id)->first();
```

I would use id for my table and avoid breaking conventions.

Comment: Happy coding. Enjoy find method ;).